# react component not re-rendering after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is rendering incorrectly when the `page` state changes
I click on the category link and it checks if the link exists in category and then should set `page` state to `category` and likewise if I click on the recipe link it should set `page` state to `recipe`.

The value of `isRecipe` and `isCategory` are correct but it only sets the `page` state correctly after refreshing the page.

It should watch the page state and if this changes then it should re-render the component

How can I re-render the component if the page state changes?

```
const categories = [
 {name: 'first', slug: 'first'}, 
 {name: 'second', slug: 'second'},
]

const recipes = [
 {name: 'firstRecipe', slug: 'firstRecipe'},
 {name: 'secondRecipe', slug: 'secondRecipe'},
]

const Categories = ({ categories, recipe, recipes }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { slug } = router.query

  const isRecipe = !!recipes.find(recipe => recipe.slug === slug)
  const isCategory = !!categories.find(cat => cat.slug === slug)

  const [page, setPage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    !!isCategory && setPage('category')
    !!isRecipe && setPage('recipe')
    }, [page])
  
  return (
    <>
      <a href="/first"> category </a>
      <a href="/firstRecipe"> recipe </a>
      {page === 'category' && <Category /> }
      {page === 'recipe' && <Recipes /> }
    </>
  )
}

export default Categories
```

Comment: add recipes and categories to useEffect dependencies

Comment: yep, what lante said is basically right, except I think you want to add isRecipe and isCategory to the dependencies instead

Comment: `page` is redundant as a dependency in `useEffect`. Anytime page changes, the component will already render again anyway. Replacing with `[isCategory, isRecipe]` seems logical, but I'm curious why you wouldn't set up your slug to just explicitly tell you this information. `isRecipe` is already a boolean and direct result of the slug itself anyway. The use of `!!` in `!!isCategory` is also a bit confusing.  `isCategory` and `isRecipe` are already booleans, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies of the `useEffect` hook are actually `isRecipe` and `isCategory` so instead of `[page]`, the effect should depend on `[isRecipe, isCategory]`.

Alternately, as the helpers (`isCategory` and `isRecipe`) are derived from the `slug`, they could be moved into the hook and then only `[slug]` would be required to set the proper hook dependencies.

Note: The `setPage` is not required to be given to the hook dependency list as it is guaranteed to be stable by React - omitting it is safe.

Ideally, the state could be avoided entirely by a simple computation like this:

```
page = null

if (isRecipe) {
  page = <Recipe />
} else if (isCategory) {
  page = <Category/>
}

...

<>
  ...
  {page}
<\>
```

There are actually three possible cases: recipe page, category page, and others that do not match the first two, which by rendering `null` will most likely result in what was anticipated by the code above.

Having less state, hooks, and mutations, results in less moving parts, thus most likely less bugs

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with the additions to the dependencies:

```
const categories = [
 {name: 'first', slug: 'first'}, 
 {name: 'second', slug: 'second'},
]

const recipes = [
 {name: 'firstRecipe', slug: 'firstRecipe'},
 {name: 'secondRecipe', slug: 'secondRecipe'},
]

const Categories = ({ categories, recipe, recipes }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { slug } = router.query

  const isRecipe = !!recipes.find(recipe => recipe.slug === slug)
  const isCategory = !!categories.find(cat => cat.slug === slug)

  const [page, setPage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    !!isCategory && setPage('category')
    !!isRecipe && setPage('recipe')
    }, [page, isRecipe, isCategory  ])
  
  return (
    <>
      <a href="/first"> category </a>
      <a href="/firstRecipe"> recipe </a>
      {page === 'category' && <Category /> }
      {page === 'recipe' && <Recipes /> }
    </>
  )
}
```